# Dragging & dropping items from one list to another in a ASP.NET page?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, javascript, ajax

I would like to move items from one list to another on a page, and I'm pretty flexible about what type of a list it is. What's the best way to do that? ASP.NET Ajax? jQuery? Anything else?

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice tutorial on CodeProject that covers dragging with ASP.NET and jQuery:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/JQueryPersistantDragDrop.aspx

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do this and PostBack instead of using AJAX to update your data based on from fields you'll need to get creative about what types of controls you use.  Page validation will complain about ASP controls like dropdownlists, listboxes, etc. if they contain selected items that weren't in the list when it was rendered.

Better to use AJAX to send back your updates or use HTML controls like unordered lists or select added via javascript and stuff the selected data in another control that doesn't complain (hiddenfield) on PostBack.  The alternative is turning off page validation and I don't think that's a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can also might look at YUI Library, I'd say it implements Drag & Drop in a very simple and flexible way:
http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/dd/

There are a lot of examples etc...